# Get all ordinals from local types view

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there a way to get all ordinals of the local types view with the ida python api?

i have tried to get all ordinals for structs with: `[ida_struct.get_struc(id).ordinal for _, id, _ in Structs()]`. This also works for enums if you replace Structs() with Enums() but this is not complete. Some structs are just in the local types view and i dont know how to get this ordinals.

Comment: Please add what did you've tried already.

Comment: i have tried to get all ordinals for structs with: `[ida_struct.get_struc(id).ordinal for _, id, _ in Structs()]`. This also works for enums if you replace Structs() with Enums() but this is not complete. Some structs are just in the local types view and i dont know how to get this ordinals.

Comment: please put that into your question so that people can see you did some work before jumping with the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it: you need to iterate over all the ordinals as defined in the local type information library returned by `get_idati()`. They are annoyingly indexed 1-up. For each ordinal you can get the corresponding `tinfo_t` with `get_numbered_type`.

```
import ida_typeinf

idati = ida_typeinf.get_idati()

for ordinal in xrange(1, ida_typeinf.get_ordinal_qty(idati)+1):
    ti = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()
    if ti.get_numbered_type(idati, ordinal):
        print ordinal, ti
```